# Populate checkbox form from database in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I`m using codeigniter to build small website. I am curious how to populate checkbox from database ?

Let`s say I have the following query;

```
$this->db->select('status');
$this->db->where('id', 3');
$this->db->get('table);
```

How to make checkbox to be checked if the result of the query above is 1 ?

Comment: try <input type='checkbox' checked='checked' /> i think you are asking how to make the checkbox checked based on the db value.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this.  It's just an idea since I can't really see EXACTLY what you're returning.  `$entry['status']` is the result from your query.

```
if($entry['status'] == 1){
                echo '<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" disabled="disabled"/>';
                    }
else {
                echo '<input type="checkbox" unchecked="unchecked" disabled="disabled"/>';
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `form_checkbox()` section of [the codeigniter form helper documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the select box checked if the status value is greater than 1 you could do something like this.

```
$result = $this->db->select('status')->get_where('table', array('id'=> 3))->row();
if($result->status > 1)
{
print '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked="checked" value="'.$result->status.'" />';
}else{
print '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="'.$result->status.'" />';
}
```

You'll want to check that the row actually returns values or you'll get a var on a non object error.  This is just an example.

Comment: Why would it ever even need to be greater than 1?

Comment: His question was - "How to make checkbox to be checked if the result of the query above is 1?"

Comment: @mhiggins Well I couldnt see why you would have it greater than 1 since they are either 1 or 0 (on or off). no?

Comment: No.  Checkboxes can be any value... it's true they have an off and on state but at the on state you could assign anything to its value.

Additionally, he wants to read the value of "status" out of the database.  That could hold anything as well so we're assuming it's numeric and has values greater than 1.

Comment: @mhiggins Yeah any value, but you would store their value in a column in a database table.  The actual cell value, what you're returning is a boolean value.

Comment: Well if 'status' stands for sent, pending or new then you would have more than just a boolean value.  The point is we don't know what status is.  We can't assume they're just storing the fact that a checkbox is checked and not its value.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me and is simple:

```
    <?php foreach($tb as $table_row){ ?>
    <input type="checkbox" <?php if ($table_row['reconciled'] == "1" {echo "checked = checked";} ?>
```